# How to input shell parametes in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface, amazon-rds

I've got two shell parameters

```
AID="subnet-00000"
BID="subnet-11111"
```

And I can't execute below statement.

```
aws rds create-db-subnet-group \
 --db-subnet-group-name dbsubnet-$service_name \
 --db-subnet-group-description "dbsubnet-$service_name" \
 --subnet-ids '[$AID, $BID]'
```

The error message is saying that
Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

How can I put my parameters into aws cli statement?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've used single-quote, the variables wont be resolved. Also you can skip square brackets:

```
aws rds create-db-subnet-group \
 --db-subnet-group-name dbsubnet-$service_name \
 --db-subnet-group-description "dbsubnet-$service_name" \
 --subnet-ids $AID $BID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I didn't know that it has already array type